# How to request page object from non Facebook app?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I'm trying send a request to

```
https://graph.facebook.com/{pageID}
```

It returns an error which tells me that I don't have an authorization token.

How can I generate an authorization token for these requests?

Comment: Also i forgot to ask:
These request are only possible from facebook app or i can somehow get the auth token for myself?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens

Comment: yes i got that. But i'm not logged in to facebook or stg like that. I just have a bunch of IDs and i want to know the page name connected to them.

Comment: If this is a one-time thing, then use Graph API Explorer. You can create access tokens right there.

Comment: It's not one-time thing and i want to do this automatically. 
I.E I have a database with IDs and i want to match them with names. If the db gets a new id i want automatically request the matching name. 

The explorer is good but not quite enough i think.

Comment: Well then just use an app access token (as long as the pages in question are public, and not access restricted in any way.)

Comment: Yep just in time :) I figured out the same. Thank you.